# How to resolve: AWS Amplify Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete with stack complaining about parameter when deploying API

Tags: aws-amplify

When deploying my new Amplify project (using `amplify api push`), I get the following error:
`Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete`

This isn't so descriptive, so I go check out CloudFormation and see that the stack has an error:

`Parameters: [AuthCognitoUserPoolId] must have values`

How do you resolve this? I thought the parameter would have automatically been supplied during configuration -- apparently not? Or is something else the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I needed to supply the `AuthCognitoUserPoolId` in `parameters.json`